# Detect hidden bluetooth device with known ID

Tags: java, bluecove

I have the target bluetooth device MAC-ID and would like to see if it is in range. How can I establish a connection to the target device, if i have it's ID and it's in hidden mode?

I'm using bluecove (java) for this.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you mean by "hidden mode."  You can connect to a device that is not discoverable, but you cannot connect to a device that is not connectable.

Generally, using JSR-82 (or Bluecove, a JSR-82 implementation) you need to have a `RemoteDevice` object in order to open a connection. The only way to get a `RemoteDevice` is via device search. It looks like you can't do a device search in your case, as the device is "hidden."

In Bluecove, you'll notice that `RemoteDevice` has a protected constructor that takes a Bluetooth address String.  You can create a subclass of `RemoteDevice` that simply makes that constructor public.  For example:

```
public class MyRemoteDevice extends javax.Bluetooth.RemoteDevice {
  public MyRemoteDevice(String addr) {
    super(addr);
  }
}
```

You can then create an instance of `MyRemoteDevice`, passing it the known MAC address, and use it to open the connection.

Comment: This works like a charm, I tested using a bluecove client application and a bluetoothserversocket on android.