# How to open a bluetooth connection given a RemoteDevice

Tags: java, bluetooth

In java (but not android) I need to connect to a 'hidden' bluetooth device.  I'm using bluecove.  I know the devices MAC address already.

In principle I can do this with:

```
StreamConnection conn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open("btspp://<mac>:1;authenticate=true;encrypt=tue;master=false;"
```

however the problem is that I need to use an authenticated connection (with a PIN).

Searching the web, I found this:
[Detect hidden bluetooth device with known ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625746/detect-hidden-bluetooth-device-with-known-id)

which allows me to create a RemoteDevice and then pass in a PIN to authenticate it, but I cannot find out how to use that RemoteDevice to then open a connection?

Answers like this:
[How to create a (javax.bluetooth.)RemoteDevice / connect with mac-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816017/how-to-create-a-javax-bluetooth-remotedevice-connect-with-mac-address?lq=1)

suggest it can be done.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I believe that I can do the pairing and authentication with:

```
RemoteDevice rd = new RemoteDevice("<mac>");
RemoteDeviceHelper.authenticate(rd, "<pin>");
```

But then how do I use that "rd" object to open a (serial) connection to my bluetooth device?

Comment: I would say that if a PIN code is needed, that's because the connexion requires to be secured following the pairing protocol (a paired device is a trusted device). Regarding the remote hidden device in question, I do not know if it requires to be paired. However, from what you provided, your **connexion URL** does stipulate : **authenticate=true** which means the connexion must be on two paired devices, hence the required PIN code which means **they are not paired**. Futhermore, there is a typo in your URL **encrypt=tue** is missing a **r** in **tue** -> encrypt=t**r**ue

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify the problem a bit

Comment: For reference for others who may follow, I was unable to find out how to do solve my problem, and instead compiled the bluez "agent.c" test code and used that for authentication outside of java (no python installed so I couldn't use simple-agent).